# Mathematica equivalent of NumPy broadcast addition for large arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, python

What is the Mathematica equivalent of the following Python code with the vectors' broadcast addition?

```python
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(5000, 1, 5);
b = np.random.rand(1, 500, 5);

result = a + b #shape: (5000, 500, 5)
```

Comment: What is the output of this addition?

Comment: The output shape is (3,8,5)

Comment: I don't know of such a built-in method.

Comment: Maybe one can play around with `Outer`.

Comment: `Outer[Plus, a[[All, 1]], b[[1]], 1]` should be fast. `broadcastedJIT[Plus, a, b]`, from my answer, is two times faster on my computer.

Answer (score 8):

For your specific case (dimension 1 only in the first two slots), this might work:

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5000, 1, 5}];
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1, 500, 5}];

c1 = Flatten[
 Outer[Plus, a, b, 2],
 {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}
 ]// RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.255

It is a bit more tedious to use `Compile` but also a bit faster:

Creating the `CompiledFunction`s:

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}},
   Table[Flatten[a, 1], {500}],
   CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];
cg = Compile[{{b, _Real, 3}},
   Table[Flatten[b, 1], {5000}],
   CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];
```

Running the actual code:

```
c2 = Plus[cf[a], cg[b]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[c1 - c2]]
```

> 0.19
>
> 0.

## Final remarks

The general case may be treated by a suitable combination of `ArrayReshape`, `MapThread`, `Outer`, and `Flatten`. Or, maybe even better, by ad-hoc compliled, `Listable` `CompiledFunction`s such as `cf` and `cg` instead of `MapThread`. Anyways, one would probably need a thourough case analysis for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
a = RandomReal[{0,1}, {3,5}]
b = RandomReal[{0,1}, {8,5}]
c = Table[a[[i]] + b[[j]], {i, Length[a]}, {j, Length[b]}]
```

`Dimension[c]` will be `{3,8,5}`, similar to `result.shape` in Python  of `(3,8,5)`

Comment: In this simplified case, also `Outer[Plus, a, b, 1]` works (and should be much faster).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher that is pretty cool!  I did not know about `Outer[]`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but it's not fast for large  arrays